# How to align two buttons right justified?

Tags: qml

Popup with 2 text boxes on top an d2 buttons at bottom aligned right:

[image: Popup with 2 text boxes on top an d2 buttons at bottom aligned right]

I am trying to create a modal/popup which has heading, followed by text content below, then below it, two buttons which are aligned towards right. How do I align those two buttons right?

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: Please ellaborate.

Answer (score 0):

```
//REQUIREMENT : Need to align rightButton towards right of popup and left button towards left of right button

import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQml 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


Popup{
    id: popup
    visible: true
    property bool bIsIconVisible: false
    Image {
        id: headingImage
        //source: "../img/Warning.svg"
        height: 22
        width: 22
        anchors{
            top: popup.top
            left: popup.left
            leftMargin: 25
            topMargin: 27
        }
        visible: true
        visible: bIsIconVisible
        
    }
    
    
    Text {
        id: headingText
        color: "white"
        visible: true
        width: 328
        height: 28
        font{
            
            pixelSize: 22
            bold: true
        }
        text: "strPopupHeadingText"
        anchors{
            top: popup.top
            left: headingImage.visible? headingImage.left : popup.left
            leftMargin: headingImage.visible? 8 : 0
            topMargin: 24
        }
        //leftPadding: 8
        // maximumLineCount: 2
        
    }
    
    
    Text {
        id: popupContent
        topPadding: 8 //padding
        //leftPadding: 24
        anchors{
            top: headingText.bottom
            topMargin: 8
        }
        text:"This data is not saved. The preview will be lost from the screen. Do you want to proceed?"
        elide: Text.ElideRight
        width: 352
        font{
            
            pixelSize:16
            
        }
        color: palette.edsGray100
        
        clip: false
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        //maximumLineCount: 2
    }
    
    
    Button {
        id: rightButton
        
        visible: true
        text: "Cancel"
        anchors{
            
            top: popupContent.bottom
            bottom: popup.bottom
            right: popup.right
            rightMargin: 24
            leftMargin: 16
            topMargin: 24
        }
        height: 44
        width: 96
    }
    
    Button{
        id: leftButton
        text: "Ok"
        
        visible: true
        anchors{
            
            top: popupContent.bottom
            bottom: popup.bottom
            right: rightButton.left
            rightMargin: 16
            topMargin: 24
            
        }
        height: 44
        width: 96
        
    }
    
    closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
    topPadding:24
    leftPadding: 24
    
    background: Rectangle {
        id: bgRect
        color: "beige"
        border.color: "green"
        border.width: 1
        height: 190
        width: 400
        
        
    }
    
}
```